# How can I read .txt file in my project root?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in MVC and I want to read a .txt file in the project root.

Because I will send this solution to my partner and he will just click run. I have tried to use `Combine` code but I have an error like "path does not exist".

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\CustomerFile-2015-07-30T1510.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
```

Comment: You will need to set the file to Copy To Output Directory = True in the properties of the file in Visual Studio and then remove the slash at the start of the file name.

Comment: You need `Server.MapPath("~\MyFileName.txt")` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`

Answer (score 3):

Since it is an ASP.NET MVC project, I would suggest to use `Server.MapPath("~")` to get the root of your ASP.NET Application.

```
var root = Server.MapPath("~");
var path = Path.Combine(root, @"CustomerFile-2015-07-30T1510.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
```